# Delete a line of text in a file that is selected in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, file, listview

I have a listview that shows messages- sender, message, time are columns. These messages are read from a text file that contains data read in from a serial port, which is later parsed and displayed in a listview with columns. Each listview item has a checkbox which indicates which indicates the item(s)/message(s) to delete. The problem that I have is I am unable to compare the listview item with the text file contents. This is the code-

```
    private void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filedata = File.ReadAllText("C:\\message.txt");
            string replacedata="";
            DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (result1.Equals(DialogResult.Yes))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lvwMessages.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (lvwMessages.Items[i].Checked)
                    {

                        replacedata = filedata.Replace(lvwMessages.SelectedItems[0] + Environment.NewLine, "");
                        lvwMessages.Items[i].Remove();
                        i--;
                    }

                }
                File.WriteAllText("C:\\message.text",replacedata);
```

**UPDATE**: The first column in my listview that is sender will be replaced by the name if the sender's number is in my contact list. So I cant compare the complete selected row with the text in the file, since that line of text in the file will contain number instead of name.

Please help.

Comment: Although I think I understand what you are trying to do, what is the real question here? This code is working? Or isn't it?

Comment: No it does not. This is the exception :`InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index`

Answer (score 1):

You can read all lines from text file by File.ReadAllLines, it will give you an array (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx).
And then you can remove single entry from it, something like this:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\message.txt").ToList();
foreach (ListViewItem selectedItem in lvwMessages.SelectedItems)
  if (lines.Contains(selectedItem.Text))
    lines.Remove(selectedItem.Text);
```

And you got exception because you have not got any selected items in your list view

Comment: Than you will have to check selectedItem.SubItems collection - and get needed subitem from there

Answer (score 0):

Extract the data from the rest of the columns and empty that line:

```
                DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result1.Equals(DialogResult.Yes))
                {
                    string re1 = "";
                    string re2 = "";
                    string replacedata = filedata;
                    for (int i = 0; i < lvwMessages.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (lvwMessages.Items[i].Checked)
                        {
                            re1 = lvwMessages.CheckedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
                            re2 = lvwMessages.CheckedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
                            replacedata = replacedata.Replace(re1 + re2, "");
                            lvwMessages.Items[i].Remove();
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\message.txt");
                    sw.Write(replacedata);
                    sw.Close();

                }
```